# Validating Zip File in VB.Net SSIS Package

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, ssis

Good Morning,

I'm using Microsoft SSIS to perform a data migration from a file system to a MS SQL database, where some of the files I'm consuming are .zip compressed folders. Some of the compressed folders have become corrupted, and I want to pass over these during the import process.

What I've created is a VB.Net Script Task to check a given directory if the zipped file is valid or not, but my Try-Catch blocks only works on the first corrupted zip file. I've tried a few variations of a Try-Catch, but I can't figure out how to get the block to proceed after the second corrupt zip.

This makes me think there's some garbage collection that needs to happen in my catch block, as the first exception populates a list of `The thread 0x000a has exited with code 0 (0x0).` followed by a `Exception thrown: 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' in System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll` whereas the second only lists out the thread exits, without an exception thrown.

What I've tried is below:

```
'Attempt to extract the zip contents
Try
    System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(str_dirExtractFrom, str_dirExtractTo)
Catch ex As InvalidDataException
    Console.WriteLine("Corrupted Zip " & str_dirExtractFrom)
End Try

'A helper function to determine if a zip file is valid:
Private Function IsValidZip(ByRef rstr_filePath As String) As Boolean
    Dim zip_file As Compression.ZipArchive
    Try
        zip_file = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead(rstr_filePath)
        'Added in attempts to force a reset
        If Not zip_file Is Nothing Then
            zip_file.Dispose()
            Return True
        End If
    Catch ex As InvalidDataException
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

'Using both together
bool_validZip = IsValidZip(str_dirExtractFrom)
If bool_validZip Then
    Try
        System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(str_dirExtractFrom, str_dirExtractTo)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Generic Exception from " & str_dirExtractFrom)
    End Try
End If
```

Strangely, going back to VBA solutions of using `On Error Resume Next` does provide the outcome I'm looking for, but I suspect there's a performance impact as it starts to take progressively longer on each corrupt zip to proceed to the next file.
The working code I have is a much simpler, and seemingly incorrect, solution:

```
On Error Resume Next
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(str_dirExtractFrom, str_dirExtractTo)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
    Err.Clear()
    Return False
On Error GoTo 0
```

Is there a way I can use a Try-Catch block in this Script Task? Do I need to alter my SSIS Control Flow to have the Script Task execute only on one file rather than query a directory? Or is the correct solution to use the simpler Resume Next?

Thank you for your time and consideration reading my help request, I greatly appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, I found a solution awhile back that has continued to serve me well.

To start off with, Try-Catch will work. In my case it just needs way longer to work than expected due to the file sizes and the resources the machine had available. Left to its own devices, in time it was able to process the second and subsequent corrupt zip files.

Analyzing it a little further, it was slightly more efficient to skip trying to assign an object from the `OpenRead` than to just directly attempt to extract the contents and catch exceptions from there. The below code gets called within a For-Each loop in part of a decision tree, but doesn't require a `Continue For`.

Part of my experience included learning that with SSIS, it's less effective to use a script task stepping through each file in directory than it is to use the built-in Foreach functionality. People more capable than I could probably do garbage collection to free up memory in the original solution I had, but using SSIS's Control Flow Foreach Container managed the memory issues I was running into significantly better.

```
Private Function ExtractValidZip(ByRef rstr_dirExtractFrom As String, ByRef rstr_dirExtractTo As String) As Boolean
' Returns
' True - successful unzip to target directory
' False - failure to unzip

    Try
        System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(rstr_dirExtractFrom, rstr_dirExtractTo)
        Return True
    Catch ex As InvalidDataException
        Return False
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Generic Exception from " & rstr_dirExtractFrom ) 'Hasn't occurred yet
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a list or array to the zip files. You are looping through the files and extracting. You need a Contiue For to keep going.

```
Private Sub ExtractZip()
    Dim str_dirExtractTo = "Where TypeOf extract to"
    Dim ListToExtract As New List(Of String) 'List of the zip files
    For Each str_dirExtractFrom In ListToExtract
        Try
            System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(str_dirExtractFrom, str_dirExtractTo)
        Catch ex As InvalidDataException
            Console.WriteLine("Corrupted Zip " & str_dirExtractFrom)
            'If you want to delete the corrupt file, do it here
            Continue For
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```